# react-native run-android error on windows: Watchman was not found in PATH

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, watchman

I install **react-native** on windows 7 x64 using the official site guide.

When i test the instalation using **react-native run-android** inside my project folder, i got the following error on **React Packager**:

[React Packager Watchman Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MMji.png)

I already tried:

- Downloaded Watchman Alpha from https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/19, extract .zip and set manually watchman.exe in the path on environment variables.

The error still appearing.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do an 
**npm -g uninstall watchman** 
**npm -g install watchman** 
and hopefully that will fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issues on windows. run **npm -g uninstall watchman**. react-native was able to run smoothly. Turns out its a file watching service with quirks on windows, you could use other file watching service. I'd also recommend using genymotion for your emulator, save yourself the headache.